# Asynchronous: Callback after loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to get some data from MongoDB, before sending them I have to make some code but at the end of the loop, my callback is not called!

```
var itemsProcessed = 0;
async.forEach(categories, function(category, cb) {
  Audit.find({
    'category_id': category._id
  }, 'created_at updated_at user_Id entreprise_id nom _id category_id', function(err, auds) {
    category.products = [];
    category.count = 0;
    if (err) res.send(err);

    category.products = auds;
    category.count = auds.length;
    itemsProcessed++;

    if (itemsProcessed == categories.length) {
      cb();
    }
  });
}, function() {
  res.json(categories);
});
```

How to send all categories after executing all the loop? Thank you for help.

Comment: you are not really using it as you're supposed to. I can see that you are catching the `error` but you are not catching the `response`. [Thinks link might help](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/)

Comment: The response is named 'auds' and I am catching it : `category.products = auds;` what wrong with my code!

Comment: Did you debug? Would be interesting to know which values `itemsProcessed` gets. Is `categories` an array? Also, why don't you call `cb` right after `res.json(categories)`?

Comment: `if (err) res.send(err);` This doesn't look alright as well, imho. isn't it supposed to be `if(err){rese.send(err)}` ?

Comment: @trincot : server-1 categories.length 50
server-1 itemsProcessed 50   normally it should execute the callback!

Comment: @ZombieChowder : Two are valid ( because i have one instruction if I have error) but yours is better for readability. thanks

Comment: @trincot each length I forgot and in each condition please? I have one condition : itemsProcessed  is a number  and categories.length is the category length so I dont understand each length you mean ! Thank you so much

Comment: You are right, I take back my comment. So what is the debugged value of the condition expression? I would place `console.log(itemsProcessed, categories.length, itemsProcessed == categories.length);` just before the `if` and in the `if` `console.log("about to execute", cb);` Does the code in the if block get executed? What if you replace the callback with a simple callback that just logs its execution?

Answer (score 1):

You should better use the combination of map, await async, and Promise.all.

It works like

```
let a=array.map(dbFunction);
a=await Promise.all(a);
res.send({a});
```

Your case, your code will look like

```
try {
let resp = categories.map(async (category) => {
    const auds = await Audit.find(
      { 'category_id': category._id },
      'created_at updated_at user_Id entreprise_id nom _id category_id'
    );
    category.products = auds;
    category.count = auds.length;
    return category;
  });
  resp = Promise.all(resp);
  res.send({ resp });
} catch (error) {
  res.send({ error });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Waqas , but I need to understand why my code is not working! Thank you so much